# Custom output data from one table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need your help and your advice. I have a problem from output data using PHP and MySQL. This my table:

[image]

I wish output data to user like this:

```
1. Account: Budi, schedule_date = 2
2. Account: Randi, schedule_date = 1
3. Account: Ipul, schedule_date = 2
4. Account: Sari, schedule_date = 5
```

My script

```
$date = $_GET['url'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mst_schedule WHERE schedule_date LIKE '%$date'") or die (mysql_error());
while ($data1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT *, count(*) as schedule_date FROM mst_schedule WHERE schedule_account='$data1[schedule_account]'");
$data2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2);
echo $data2['schedule_date'];
echo "<br>";
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: we know this is very clear in your head. Can you help our heads?

Comment: you want a count? do a `select name,count(*) as theCount from t1 group by name` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this queries in your code:

```
$sql1 = "SET @rank = 0";
$sql2  = "SELECT @rank := ( @rank +1 ) AS id, schedule_account AS Account, COUNT(schedule_date) AS schedule_date "
        . "FROM TBL_SCHEDULE GROUP BY schedule_account";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT schedule_account, count(*) as 'Cnt' FROM tbl_schedule GROUP BY schedule_account
```

And check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d73764/1).

Comment: @akashi - No problem. You can return the favor by upvoting or accepting my answer.